# python libsvm core dump

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, libsvm, coredump

I have Python code that works fine on my development environment (Ubuntu 12.04) but dumps core on my production environment (a Linode running CentOS).

```
*** glibc detected *** python2.7: double free or corruption (out): 0x090cba60 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i686/nosegneg/libc.so.6(+0x717b1)[0xb763d7b1]
/lib/i686/nosegneg/libc.so.6(+0x73f01)[0xb763ff01]
/home/michael/libsvm-3.16/python/../libsvm.so.2(svm_free_model_content+0xe2)[0xb6e0c6b2]
/home/michael/libsvm-3.16/python/../libsvm.so.2(svm_free_and_destroy_model+0x2c)[0xb6e0c70c]
/home/michael/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so(ffi_call_SYSV+0x17)[0xb71e375f]
/home/michael/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so(ffi_call+0x5b)[0xb71e35ab]
/home/michael/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so(_ctypes_callproc+0x32d)[0xb71d82ad]
/home/michael/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so(+0x703e)[0xb71d003e]
python2.7(PyObject_Call+0x4a)[0x805d90a]
python2.7(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3c0a)[0x80e04ba]
python2.7(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7bb)[0x80e2c1b]
python2.7[0x813ee2a]
python2.7(PyObject_Call+0x4a)[0x805d90a]
python2.7[0x80657f1]
python2.7(PyObject_Call+0x4a)[0x805d90a]
python2.7(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x42)[0x80db852]
python2.7[0x80af616]
python2.7[0x80a928e]
python2.7[0x808e024]
python2.7[0x8067c5b]
python2.7[0x808c079]
python2.7(PyDict_SetItem+0x87)[0x808cfa7]
python2.7(_PyModule_Clear+0x123)[0x8090693]
python2.7(PyImport_Cleanup+0x175)[0x80f2ca5]
python2.7(Py_Finalize+0x10c)[0x80ffacc]
python2.7(Py_Main+0x53d)[0x8058c1d]
python2.7(main+0x1b)[0x805839b]
/lib/i686/nosegneg/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0xb75e2ce6]
python2.7[0x80582e1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0817d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:00 430104     /home/michael/bin/python2.7
0817d000-081ab000 rw-p 00134000 ca:00 430104     /home/michael/bin/python2.7
081ab000-081b4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
...
```

It happens frequently, but not all the time.  Furthermore, if I remove *.pyc files in my libsvm subdirectory, then it seems to work without fail, but once the *.pyc files are regenerated (after the first run), it tends to dump core again.

Furthermore, if I attempt to pipe standard error to a file, it never crashes.

Some information that may be relevant:

- It only started happening when I installed Python 2.7.  It wasn't happening with Python 2.6
- Python2.7 is installed into my home directory (from source, since there are no python2.7 packages for CentOS)

How should I approach this problem?  Where is the problem most likely to be?  Is it in the libsvm source or the Python wrapper?  I'm pretty sure it's not in my Python source, since I shouldn't be able to crash the interpreter like that.

**EDIT**

I retrained the models on the production environment and the problem appears to have gone away.  For reference, here are the diffs between the dev and production environments for both the models I'm using.

Header diff first model:

```
4,7c4,7
< total_sv 8858
< rho -0.500251 -0.215012 2.99972 -0.00159202 0.000223509 1.00003
< label 3 2 1 0
< nr_sv 549 6095 587 1627
---
> total_sv 8782
> rho -2.99981 0.000329574 -1.00015 -0.335094 -0.999424 -0.66958
> label 0 3 2 1
> nr_sv 1586 535 6083 578
-bash-4.1$ diff model.svm model2.svm | head -n 20
4,7c4,7
< total_sv 8858
< rho -0.500251 -0.215012 2.99972 -0.00159202 0.000223509 1.00003
< label 3 2 1 0
< nr_sv 549 6095 587 1627
```

Header diff second model:

```
4,7c4,7
< total_sv 116
< rho 2.30068 -0.145028 0.169511 -1.09344 0.723723 -0.865381
< label 3 0 2 1
< nr_sv 18 32 34 32
---
> total_sv 132
> rho 0.72381 -2.00473 -0.220492 -0.962109 0.998243 -0.14499
> label 0 1 3 2
> nr_sv 43 35 18 36
```

Comment: That's a really strange crash, because if you look in the `svm_free_model_content` function in libsvm, you'll see that it has two guards: `if(model_ptr->free_sv && model_ptr->l > 0 && model_ptr->SV != NULL)` and `if(model_ptr->sv_coef)`, which make me think that you actually have an inconsistent `svm_model` which gets passed to this function, that is not NULL, because `svm_free_and_destroy_model` checks for that kind of thing. Are you getting the expected predictions before the crash or maybe a crash in a different place?

Comment: Also, does this crash occur when you train your models or when you try to compute predictions?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  To answer your questions: it happens only when I compute predictions.  I'm getting expected predictions before the crash.

Comment: In this case, could you by any chance share a sample model file?

Comment: I think I've found the problem.  I have libsvm 3.1 installed on my dev machine, and libsvm 3.16 installed in the production environment.  I was using models that were trained on the dev environment.  If I retrain the models in the production environment, the crash no longer occurs.  Thank you for your suggestions (mentioning inconsistent svm_model put me on the right track).

Comment: Oh, well, that makes sense. They must have changed some stuff in the model file format. I'm glad I helped you solve it :)

Comment: By the way, could you please do a diff on the headers of a model file produced by libsvm 3.1 and one produced by libsvm 3.16 for your particular setup and post it as an answer? Some other people might find it useful :)

Comment: Done.  I don't see any significant difference, though...

Comment: It's happening again.  I've reproduced it in my dev environment by installing libsvm 3.16.  I fired up a debug build.  Are you still interested in looking into this?  I can share the models and the offending python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the error is an uninitialized pointer in svm_load_model, and an unchecked call to `free`.  Here's a patch:

```
misha@misha-diginnos:~$ diff libsvm-3.16/svm.cpp.original libsvm-3.16/svm.cpp -p
*** libsvm-3.16/svm.cpp.original        2013-03-17 17:34:00.235661297 +0900
--- libsvm-3.16/svm.cpp 2013-03-17 17:39:29.677294903 +0900
*************** svm_model *svm_load_model(const char *mo
*** 2747,2752 ****
--- 2747,2753 ----
        model->probB = NULL;
        model->label = NULL;
        model->nSV = NULL;
+     model->sv_indices = NULL;

        char cmd[81];
        while(1)
*************** void svm_free_model_content(svm_model* m
*** 2973,2980 ****
        free(model_ptr->probB);
        model_ptr->probB= NULL;

!       free(model_ptr->sv_indices);
!       model_ptr->sv_indices = NULL;

        free(model_ptr->nSV);
        model_ptr->nSV = NULL;
--- 2974,2984 ----
        free(model_ptr->probB);
        model_ptr->probB= NULL;

!     if (model_ptr->sv_indices)
!     {
!         free(model_ptr->sv_indices);
!         model_ptr->sv_indices = NULL;
!     }

        free(model_ptr->nSV);
        model_ptr->nSV = NULL;
```

I've notified the authors.  They're aware of the problem and will address it in the next version.

Comment: Well, I'm glad the authors of the library managed to help you. It took forever when I asked for their help. Unfortunately, libsvm is maintained by researchers, who have little experience with production-grade code.

Comment: They're doing a relatively good job, in my opinion.  My only wish is that they could be even more open with their source, like sharing it as a git repo on github.com.  If they shared their development branch, problems like this wouldn't cause as much pain.