# libsvm - python on mac alert malloc error

Tags: python, svm, libsvm

Im using this for making classifier.

when i let do svm_predict,

this alerts

```
Accuracy = 0% (0/1) (classification)
[2.0]
(0.0, 4.0, nan)
[[0.12612545919459253, 0.43547967330944765, 0.05800756627730365, 0.036116536312615084, 0.16190484785290027, 0.09137947289650544, 0.09098644415663576]]
Python(4682) malloc: *** error for object 0x5: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

param i sent was about 200-rows, like

```
data = { 1:5, 2:5, 3:5, ~, 200: 5 }
a, b, c = svm_predict([0]*len([data]), [data], model)
```

what i can do?

Comment: I would try to train and test using the sample `heart_scale` file and see if you get the same error. If you don't, probably you have bad formatting somewhere. If you do, probably should reinstall.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15459000/1174378). It might be related.

Comment: Try to reproduce the error using the executables directly (not through Python).  If you can reproduce it, step through the executable with the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this is related with above question.

But following this, every problems was completely solved.

The way is operate `A`: `Train` with `garbage value` (unrelated).

And very important thins is to use not `A`'s model, but `B`'s model already you made.

Finally, solution is to operate `Train` as `flag`.